# Can Stoicism be seen as something close to Buddhism in some aspects?

Tags: academic-buddhism

I am asking this question, for I try to follow much of [*Stoicism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoicism), and I can see that there are certain similarities. But there are also many differences. Could some aspects be the same or at least alike?

For example, Stoics assert that unhappiness and evil are the results of ignorance. If one is cruel, it is because he is unaware of his own universal reason. If one is unhappy, it is because he "forgot" how his true nature actually operates (these concepts seem to me very similar to the Buddha Nature, which belongs to all living beings, but is often in a latent state).

PS : I am sorry if the tags are wrong, I am new here.

Comment: There are two other topics about Stoicism on this site -- [What does Buddhism add to a Stoic?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/18688/254) and [Is there evidence of a Buddhist influence on Greek Stoicism?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/2801/254).

Comment: I crate a new post in SC. Hope someone will answer. https://discourse.suttacentral.net/t/is-stoicism-close-to-buddhist-teaching-what-are-the-salaint-differences/6465

Answer (score 2):

Stoicism can be seen as very similar to Buddhism in that it appeals to an ultimately indefinable reality which, through the denial of ego, awareness of which brings harmony to life.  Also, the stoic acceptance of whatever happens being in accord with nature is like non-attachment.  A Buddhist writer I read recently said that they are in many ways the same other than the Buddhist has greater joy to the extent to which their ego has dissolved.

Stoics permit suicide in a wider range of cases than Buddhists, although the principle that suicide is an option when spiritual practice is no longer possible is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many people quoting stoicism in Buddhist teaching. Mainly Bhante Sujato from Sutta Central. They use Stoicism to discuss rebirth and Kamma and even Dependent origination.
The way I understand only Buddha came up with the clear path to attain Nibbana.
Buddha is the only person who proclaimed completer four noble truths.

Comment: I didn't find those quotes here: https://discourse.suttacentral.net/search?q=stoic -- can you reference/link to any?

Answer (score 0):

You might watch this discussion between Robert Wright and Massimo Pigliucci: [THE WRIGHT SHOW -- STOICISM VS. BUDDHISM](http://meaningoflife.tv/videos/38678)

Comment: Thanks for the link. If you could also summarize, even one sentence of what you remember of it, then so much the better.

Answer (score -1):

All knowledge is conditioned by the same cause. The closer a teacher is to the cause, the more his teachings are similar to Buddhism.